# An error occurred while configuring the solution to restore NuGet packages on build. The operation has timed out

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package-restore

When I right-click my solution and click "enable nuget package restore"

I get the message:

> Configuring the solution to restore NuGet packages on build...

And after that the error:

> An error occurred while configuring the solution to restore NuGet packages on build. The operation has timed out

What can it be?

Comment: In updating the solution a number of files (including `nuget,exe,` – the command line NuGet tool) are downloaded. Is your internet connection functioning?

Comment: Some of the NuGet services are currently down so you may be affected by that. http://status.nuget.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuget is down right now, so this why you might this issue with your solution.